# Authorize.NET GetCustomerProfile not returning data

Tags: authorize.net, authorize.net-cim

I have been using Authorize.NET's GetCustomerProfile for many years and suddenly today the response is not returning a payment profile. It just returns an array of profiles, but all important fields (such as `payment`) are null.

(This is part of their CIM feature where an 'obfuscated' payment profile is returned and should be something like XXXX1234)

I am using a generated proxy within Visual Studio to the URL `https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?WSDL` (which generates a References.cs file)

Comment: Have you tried it in the sandbox? Does it give you the same results?

Comment: actually yes it does - I figured out the issue and I'm about to respond - hoping it may help others (and hoping they don't break it like this ever again)....

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on the CreateCustomerPaymentProfile SOAP call (via .NET auto-generated proxy) that just started yesterday, 11/3/2015, even though we've been successfully interfacing the SOAP CIM for a couple years.

I was able to "fix" the issue by doing an "Update Service Reference" in Visual Studio to regenerate the proxy classes based on their latest WSDL. There were several changes in the WSDL.

Specifically, on my end it appeared as if the response was not including a value for the customerPaymentProfileId after being successfully created on their end. In reality, they were in fact still sending this value, but there was a new field above it in the XML response, customerProfileId. As Simon_Weaver mentioned in his answer, the proxy classes generated by Visual Studio have explicit ordering of fields that are required for proper deserialization. The addition of this previously "unknown" field above a known field caused it to break my code.

Luckily this new customerProfileId was included in their latest WSDL so an "Update Service Reference" and recompile fixed my issue.

I informed Authorize.net support of my issue in great detail and told them they need to include any new fields at the end of the "sequence" in the WSDL document in order to not break and clients using older versions of the WSDL. So far I have not heard a response from them, but I would encourage anyone else who experienced this issue, even if you've already worked-around it, to report it to them at support@authorize.net so they don't accidently do this again.

Comment: I did hear back from authorize.net support today, and they pointed me to this forum: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/CIM-WSDL-Breaking-Change-on-11-3/td-p/52828  where others are reporting the exact same issue on 11/3. Now that many of us have worked around this, if they decide to roll back the change they're going to break our interfaces again!

Comment: it absolutely should be possible to 'fix' it with an Update reference, but the problem is that their WSDL doesn't even contain the field `billTo` under `CustomerPaymentProfileBaseType` and I don't even know how that's possible. So I had to add it too.

Comment: they did write back to me and said 'We are sorry for any inconvenience this caused you though I can advise these changes will stay current.' Obviously it didn't make it to a developer yet - but they must have many people with this issue

Answer (score 1):

Well hello Simon!
It looks like Authorize.NET updated their service with new fields but forgot to add them to the WSDL.

This is a sample request that I sent (intercepted using [Fiddler](http://fiddlertool.com)):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo3vYq2eC/5VIuiUcm2hEtw8AABBBJr/dLQF7z02Y7UKwphq24W1n9j0XlQ1MiAlOjy5fO14ACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetCustomerProfile xmlns="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/">
            <merchantAuthentication>
                <name>95U6bwXXXXX</name>
                <transactionKey>8tf62gV7XXXXXX</transactionKey>
            </merchantAuthentication>
            <customerProfileId>37745529</customerProfileId>
        </GetCustomerProfile>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is the response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <GetCustomerProfileResponse xmlns="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/">
            <GetCustomerProfileResult>
                <resultCode>Ok</resultCode>
                <messages>
                    <MessagesTypeMessage>
                        <code>I00001</code>
                        <text>Successful.</text>
                    </MessagesTypeMessage>
                </messages>
                <profile>
                    <merchantCustomerId>33938</merchantCustomerId>
                    <email>4691705@EXAMPLE.COM</email>
                    <customerProfileId>37745529</customerProfileId>
                    <paymentProfiles>
                        <CustomerPaymentProfileMaskedType>
                            <billTo>
                                <firstName>TEST</firstName>
                                <lastName>USER</lastName>
                                <company>Defender Razor</company>
                                <address>1 RODEO DRIVE</address>
                                <city>BEVERLY HILLS</city>
                                <state>CA</state>
                                <zip>90210</zip>
                                <country>UNITED STATES</country>
                            </billTo>
                            <customerProfileId>0</customerProfileId>
                            <customerPaymentProfileId>34313485</customerPaymentProfileId>
                            <payment>
                                <creditCard>
                                    <cardNumber>XXXX5108</cardNumber>
                                    <expirationDate>XXXX</expirationDate>
                                </creditCard>
                            </payment>
                        </CustomerPaymentProfileMaskedType>
                    </paymentProfiles>
                </profile>
            </GetCustomerProfileResult>
        </GetCustomerProfileResponse>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Everything here is correct - as you can see the `payment` node is being sent correctly.

However - with .NET deserialization the order of attributes matters - as specified in the generated `References.cs` file.

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=0)]
```

It turns out that two new fields were added to the response `billTo` and `customerProfileId` but they weren't added to the WSDL.

So when trying to deserialize the field `billTo` is found but that isn't what was expected - so everything ends up null.

If you add these two lines (and be careful to add them to exactly this type) then you can regenerate the references.cs file (by right clicking on the service reference and regenerating the file).

If you were generating your proxy from the URL `https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx?WSDL` then you will need to download this file locally as `Service.wsdl` and generate the proxy from there.

```
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="billTo" type="tns:CustomerAddressType"/>
   <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="customerProfileId" type="s:long" />

 <s:complexType name="CustomerPaymentProfileMaskedType">
    <s:complexContent mixed="false">
      <s:extension base="tns:CustomerPaymentProfileBaseType">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="billTo" type="tns:CustomerAddressType"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="customerProfileId" type="s:long" />
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="customerPaymentProfileId" type="s:long" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="payment" type="tns:PaymentMaskedType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="driversLicense" type="tns:DriversLicenseMaskedType" />
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="taxId" type="s:string" />
        </s:sequence>
      </s:extension>
    </s:complexContent>
  </s:complexType>
```

I lost over 12 hours of payments before this was detected. Fortunately I have the customer's emails but this was very bad. You can't just add fields to a response where the order matters. And even worse than that you can't just forget to add them to the WSDL.

This was the quick fix for me. I may switch to using the proper API at some point - and I've reported this to Authorize.net hoping they may respond too.

This is the differences in References.cs after I made my change. As you can see the `Order` property has been incremented :

[image]